# A set of sequences and their relations among each other

Tags: nt.number-theory, set-theory, prime-numbers

Define an order $o_p(e)$ as follows:  for each even $e$, get a unique sum $p+q$ of primes $p$, $q$ (if there is one).  Choose $p$ such that $p$ is the least prime in the list of primes that have been used so far.  (There is a record of the unique pair chosen according to an algorithm.  It is a function $f(e) = (p,q)$ that chooses from the possible pairs for $e$ the one that is most generous in making sure each prime gets a chance to be chosen as much as possible.) Then $o_p(e_i) =$ the number of times the prime $p$ has been chosen up to and including $e_i$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th prime.

We have as chosen pairs so far
6 = 3+3
10=5+5
12=5+7
14=3+11
16=3+13
18=7+11

So we can compute the first few entries from each sequence:

$o_3(e) = <0,2,2,2,3,4,4,...>$

$o_5(e) = <0,0,2,3,3,3,3,...>$

$o_7(e) = <0,0,0,1,1,1,1,...>$

$o_{11}(e) = <0,0,0,0,1,1,1,...>$

$o_{13}(e) = <0,0,0,0,0,1,1,...>$

It seems it might be true that if $p \le q$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes, then eventually for every $e$ we have

$p*o_p(e) \subseteq q*o_q(e)$.

The sequence $p*o_p(e)$ is the sequence $o_p(e)$ with each coordinate multiplied by p.  I'm trying to make a set of sequences like this where a (sequence for a) prime eventually dominates the (sequences for) primes below it.

Edit: $o_p(e)$ is a sequence determined by a particular prime $p$ which is variable. Each coordinate in the sequence is about an even, which is possibly the sum of $p$ plus another prime on this generous ordering. Each $o_p(e_i)$ is the number of times $p$ has been chosen as a sum of primes to get $e_k$ for $k \le i$.

Comment: Can you say more about the quantifiers in your definition of $e_i(p)$? Is it $e_i(p)=\min\{n:\exists q\text{ prime},m\text{ s.t. } e_i=np+mq\}$?

Comment: Isn’t this trivial? $e_i(p)=1$ for all $i$ in the infinite set $\{(p+q)/2:q\text{ prime}\}$ (assuming $e_i=2i$).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas thank you I have been thinking of it in different ways, re-wrote the question after some thought

Comment: @EmilJeřábek yes thank you

Comment: We could also be very generous and include the number of times p can be used, including all the prime sums for any e.